# Why does Emacs create a file that starts with ~?

Tags: unix, emacs

I'm new to Unix. Whenever I exit the Emacs editor after editing a file say foo.c by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I see a new file automatically created called `~foo.c`. What is it and why is it automatically created?

Please help me... Thank you!

Comment: Hi Joe, Welcome to stack overflow. This question is off-topic here, because it's not programming related. In a few minutes it will be closed. You will have much better luck if you ask this quest at SuperUser.com or Unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: The file would be named `foo.c~` not `~foo.c`.

Comment: @Alan: It is not a good idea to recommend people to repost their questions on a different site. After it is closed it will be migrated automatically.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, I knew that stack *use* to do that, but the text for "Off Topic Close" no longer mentions it, so I wasn't sure, but now I know for certain!

Comment: Just a reminder, if you use `dired (c-x d)` you can remove backups and autosaves by pressing `~` and/or `#`  followed by `x`

Answer (score 7):

You can disable backups, but that's a bad idea for obvious reasons. If you dislike seeing them alongside the current file, you can tell Emacs to store them somewhere else.

I use the following in my ~/.emacs.d/init.el file:

```
;; Write backups to ~/.emacs.d/backup/
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/backup"))
      backup-by-copying      t  ; Don't de-link hard links
      version-control        t  ; Use version numbers on backups
      delete-old-versions    t  ; Automatically delete excess backups:
      kept-new-versions      20 ; how many of the newest versions to keep
      kept-old-versions      5) ; and how many of the old
```

Answer (score 5):

They are backup files, so you can roll back to the previous version of the file if you need to.

If they bother you, just clean them up periodically with:

```
find . -name "*~" -depth 1 -delete
```

This will clear all the `*~` files found in the current directory, remove `-depth 1` if you want to clean them recursively in all sub-directories too, of course, any file ending with `~` will get killed, so apply caution.

Of course, you can tell Emacs to stop making them if you want, just add this line to your `.emacs` file.

```
(setq make-backup-files nil) ;; do not make backup files
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is a temporary file created when editing the file.

The proper way to save and exit in emacs is Ctrl-x Ctrl-c (I don't believe you let go of Ctrl in between the x and c)
Please see [here](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs210/help/emacs.html) for more emacs help.

Comment: Since we're correcting the use of Ctrl+XC (which I'm sure the OP meant to mean Ctrl for both) - C-x C-c is the proper notation, also this just closes Emacs, it doesn't save and close.  You need to do C-x C-s, C-x C-c to save and close.

Comment: There is no need to let go of Ctrl while doing C-x C-c.

Answer (score 1):

This is a backup file created automatically by emacs. Don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a file in Emacs, it automatically creates a backup file (what the file looked like before editing) with the “~” prefix.

If you don’t want this, see:
http://www.rpi.edu/dept/acs/rpinfo/common/Computing/Consulting/Software/Emacs/Hints/backup.html

Comment: I would expect backup file names of the format `foo.c~`. Has it been changed lately?